# How to list files in a directory that have permission to read in C#?

Tags: c#, permissions, .net-6.0

I would like to list all the files in a directory that the user has read permission. In net4, I used `IO.File.GetAccessControl`. But this is not available in net6. The class `FileIOPermission` is flagged as obsolete in net6 but it does say what replaces it.
I know that when I do open the file, I will have try/catch `UnauthorizedAccessException`. But I don't what to open ever file just to determine whether I can. Is there a way to check file permissions in net6?

Answer (score -2):

Try use impersonating access

follow: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: In addition to what @KenWhite said some explanation how impersonating a user will help with checking if they have read permission or not would greatly improve the answer (to the point it actually may answer the question as asked)